# XML Editor on Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate

I can't seem to access the xml text editor on Eclipse.  Whenever I create an xml file, after the "create xml file from" screen shows, I click next, nothing happens.  Also when I open the xml file I created, I keep getting this error message saying "failed to create path's controls".  How can I fix this?  Images are below:

Xml error message

[image: 2]

2nd error message

[image: 1]

Comment: Is that an exact error message? Can you add screenshots? Which version is this, if not the current one?

Comment: You are running an older version. Please retry with 2022-06.

Comment: You mean an older version of Eclipse?  The one I have is the IDE version

Comment: "IDE" is not a version. Yes, as I said you appear to have an older version that the current one, 2022-06. Update to 2022-06 and see if it still happens.

Comment: They don't have June 2022 version.  The ones they have on my end are March 2020, Latest Eclipse Release, and The Eclipse Project Updates.  Will one of them work since the one you recommended is not one of the options?

Comment: Is it all XML files that have issues, or just Hibernate configuration files? And download.eclipse.org plainly shows that there is a June 2022 version. I can't see the screen that you're seeing without it, but it is the latest one.

Comment: I downloaded the 2022 version but there is no option showing to create an xml file.  I clicked New>Other> and the only options are General, Git, Gradle, Java, Maven, and Oomph.  No XML.  The March 2020 version (the one Ive been using for my assignments) has the XML option

Comment: You needed to download the 2022-06 version of the same package you already had. Each package has a different combination of contents. You likely had the Enterprise Java version, with more things installed. You need to verify that you install the up to date versions of what you already had--*which might include more than just what's in the download*.